# P5js, How do I get position of a color pixel using get()?

Tags: arrays, colors, get

I'm a p5js beginner. Hello! :)

I'm tring to place ellipse on blue pixels of the image.
I've briefly made an image to show what I'm tring to do.
[explanation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXtml.jpg)

I thought I could get the position of the blue pixels by using get().
This is the link of the code I'm working on!
https://editor.p5js.org/yeonsupark98/sketches/y3xFd9Gd6

I tried googling, but there were little information related to this 
(Maybe I'm not good at searching...)

Your Answer would help me a lot!
Thankyou for your time!

```
let img; 
let c=[];

function preload(){ img = loadImage('cat.jpg');

}

function setup(){ 
createCanvas(700,500); 
fur();

}

function fur(){

img.loadPixels();

for(let i=0;i<img.width+img.height*4; i+=4){ 
img.pixels[i+0] = 255; 
img.pixels[i+1] = c; 
img.pixels[i+2] = 255; 
img.pixels[i+3] = 255; }

}

function draw(){ 
ellipse(c,c,25,25); 
}
```

One thing I'm sure of is that 'img.pixels[i+0]' means red. and '~[i+1]' meaning green and so on.
But I'm not sure how this actually works.

this was the first thing I've tried.

```
r(let i=0;i<img.width+img.height*4; i+=4){ 
img.pixels[i+0] = new ellipse;
}

function ellipse(){ 
ellipse(25,25,25,25); 
}
```

ellipse(position x, position y, size,size);
I know putting 25 doesn't make any sense, but I didn't know what to put there.
so I ended up on the first code I'm showing you

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to create the image you wanted to make https://editor.p5js.org/kylesmith090502/sketches/-3Pl0s8SY

### How to get position of color

As shown below, I went through every pixel and saved all pixels of a certain colors to an array. I retrieved the `X,Y` position of all the pixels of a specific color by calculating similar to this: `(i % imageWidth = x, i / imageWidth = y)`.

```js
  // Loop through every pixel
  for(let i=0; i < img.width * img.height; i++) {
    // Get the distance from the pixel will be top and left
    const pixelTop = Math.floor(i / img.width);
    const pixelLeft = Math.floor(i % img.width);
    const pixelIndex = (pixelTop * img.width + pixelLeft) * 4;
       
    // If the pixel is a certain color we save it.
    if (
      img.pixels[pixelIndex+0] < 127 &&
      img.pixels[pixelIndex+1] < 127 &&
      img.pixels[pixelIndex+2] >= 127
    ) {
      c.push({x: pixelLeft, y: pixelTop});
    }
  }
```

In this next example, I took my function above and optimized it by only checking every 16 pixels horizontally and vertically to decrease the amount of pixels I'm checking.

```js
  // Distance between ellipsis
  const gridGap = 16;
  
  // Limit how high `i` could go. There probably is an easier way to do this.
  for(let i=0; i < img.width * img.height / (gridGap ** 2); i++) {
    // Get the distance from the pixel will be top and left
    const pixelTop = Math.floor((i * gridGap) / img.width) * gridGap;
    const pixelLeft = Math.floor(i % (img.width / gridGap)) * gridGap;
    // Calculate the index it would have on the imageData.data array
    const pixelIndex = ((pixelTop * img.width) + pixelLeft) * 4;
       
    // If the pixel is blue, we save it and will later put an ellipse there
    if (
      img.pixels[pixelIndex+0] < 127 &&
      img.pixels[pixelIndex+1] < 127 &&
      img.pixels[pixelIndex+2] >= 127
    ) {
      c.push({x: pixelLeft, y: pixelTop});
    }
  }
```

I did notice what I wrote was choppy along the border of the image, so it's not perfect. If you want it to be clean along the edges you could extend the `img.width` and `img.height` by a little bit, depending on your priority.